# Como extraer datos de un grafico dinamico

Tags: python, bootstrap, web, scraping, beautifulsoup

He estado interesado en **data science** y con esto de las **criptos**. Se me hizo interesante tratar de extraer datos y de **coinmarketcap**. Sin embargo no logro encontrar en que parte de la pagina se almacenan los datos de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen es la gráfica y lo que quiero extraer son los datos (fecha y precio).

¿Alguien tiene idea de como lograrlo? Ya intenté inspeccionar la pagina pero no encuentro la fuente de información.

https://coinmarketcap.com/es/currencies/bitcoin/

Answer (score 0):

Ese gráfico se carga de manera dinámica con los datos que devuelve su propia API.

Tienes todo indicado en su [documentación](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) y para uso personal es gratis (aunque está bastante limitada).

En caso de que quieras hacerlo de vía scraping vas a tener que utilizar selenium o similares.